# Mi imagen no se ve cuando la pido por serverless nodejs

Tags: aws, lambda

Tengo este probelma con serverless, y es que quiero mandar la imagen de mi aws s3 bucket a mi frontend, estoy enviando la imagen por medio de un array de bytes, pero no me logra funcionar, en mi backend estoy usando serverless con express, al momento de mandar la imagen hago lo siguiente

```
const result = await controll.getImage(req.query.key)
console.log(`GET: img ${req.query.key}`);
res.setHeader('isBase64Encoded', true);
result.Body.transformToByteArray().then(resp => {
    // console.log(resp);
    res.send(resp);
})
```

Y en mi frontend

```
axios.get(`/img?key=${code}`
, {
    responseType: 'blob'
}
).then(resp => {
    setImgSoruce(URL.createObjectURL(resp.data))
    setLoadimg(false)
}).catch(err => {
    setImgSoruce(defImg)
    setLoadimg(false)
})
```

Ahora bien, si uso solo nodejs en express la imagen se visualiza correctamente, ya cuando aplico los camibos de serverless, la imagen no se logra visualizar bien, no se si se tiene que hacer un paso extra para que mandar la informacion con serverless?

Estoy usando serverless 2